# Finding a partial match in string and return position of mismatches in R

Tags: r

I want to find the location of a short DNA sequence ("ACA GCA CAC") in a gene sequence and identify any mismatches between the sequence and the full gene. The sequence may have one or more mismatches to the full genetic sequence, either in the form of additions, deletions or substitutions.

A function that can search for partial matches and return location of the mismatches based on a set limit of allowed mismatches would be ideal.

Example:

```
# DNA sequence
seq <- "ACTGCGGCAC"
# Full gene sequence
gene <- "AGCCTGCTGACAGCGCACGATCAGTTCAAGGCAACACTGCCCGAGGCT"

match <- function(seq, gene, max_mismatch = 3){
   matches <- list(
     match1 = list(
      matching_nucleotides = setNames(object = character(length = 2), c("start", "end")),
      mismatch_positions = setNames(object = character(length = max_mismatch), paste0("mismatch_", 1:max_mismatch)),
      sequence_aligment = <something>
     ),
     match2 = list( <...> )
   )

   # Work the magic here
   
   return(matches)
}

match(seq, gene, max_mismatch = 3)
```

Output of the above example should be something like this:

```
$match1 =
$matching_nucleotides
start: 10  end: 18
$mismatch_positions
mismatch_1: 12 (replacement)  mismatch_2: 15 (insertion) mismatch_3: ''
$sequence_alignment
seq:  ACTGCGGCAC
      || ||| |||
gene: ACAGCG-CAC
```

Comment: Please show what you expect the output to be. I'm confused about "find the location of" followed by "mismatches". In this case, your `seq` has no matching substring so no location can be found.

Comment: Perhaps you mean to find min-string-distances for every possible substring within `gene` against the string defined in `seq`? For that, what are you using to calculate a string-distance?

Comment: Use `adist` or `EM` algorithm for learning motif sequence

Comment: What if there are multiple subsequences within the gene that match the given seq with costs of not more than 3? what do you do in that case?

Comment: @r2evans I've updated my post to better clarify desired output.  I think min-string-distances is what I amlooking for.

Comment: So that means that you want to compare `seq` with all 40 possible 9-long substrings of `gene` and return the position with the minimum string-distance? Is your question that you don't know how to iterate over substrings of `gene`, or that you don't know about the `stringdist` package that will calculate the "distance"?

Comment: (1) If you by *"string-distance"* mean difference, then yes. I want a list of possible matches from the closest match up to the least within the threshold defined in `max_mismatch`. (2) I do not know how to iterate, and this is part of the problem. (3) I hadn't heard of `stringdist` until now.

Answer (score 1):

use `adist`. This will return an array showing the number of `ins`ertions, `del`etions and `sub`stitutions. It will also return the offsets which is the starting and end positions of the seq in the gene:

```
adist(seq, gene, partial = TRUE, counts = TRUE)
     [,1]
[1,]    1
attr(,"counts")
, , ins

     [,1]
[1,]    0

, , del

     [,1]
[1,]    0

, , sub

     [,1]
[1,]    1

attr(,"offsets")
, , first

     [,1]
[1,]   10

, , last

     [,1]
[1,]   18
```

---

To get the seq from gene, do:

```
a <- adist(seq, gene, partial = TRUE, costs = 3, counts = TRUE)
do.call(substr, c(gene,as.list(attr(a, 'offsets'))))
[1] "ACAGCGCAC"
```

You can see that the letter `A` in `seq` needs to be substituted with letter `G` for the two to be exactlythe same

---

Note,to obtain positions of mismatch, find where the seq is not equal to the extracted seq. I am not sure as to whether you need the position in the gene or in the seq. So will leave this one out

Comment: Thanks this is most helpful! In addition, I still would like a comparison of sequences and listing of where they are alike or differ.

Comment: @PålBjartan so do you want `A` `G` as the solution or do you want 6 or do you want the position in the gene?? I could not answer this questions thats why I did not provide the code. But it should be strainghtforward. ie `which(unlist(strsplit(seq, '')) != unlist(strsplit(results, '')))`

Comment: You ask good questions that warrants more deliberate consideration on my part. For this task, however, I wanted to retrieve positions in `gene` where `seq` partial match starts, where it ends, and positions where the differences can be found.

Comment: @PålBjartan find the positions that mismatch using the code I provided in the comments above, then add these to the starting position, ie 10

Comment: However, `which(unlist(strsplit(seq, '')) != unlist(strsplit(results, '')))` works fine if a letter is replaced. However, if there are additions or deletions to `seq`, it will return the position of every letter thereafter. E.g. setting `seq <- "ACAGCGGCAC"` will return `7·8·9·10`. There has to be a way to move the letters in the shorter vector one place down so the subsequent letters will match.

Comment: @PålBjartan You should consider asking the question detailing what you have, and what you want. Notice that in this question, you never gave and example of the solution you are looking for. Also use 2-3 examples, in each clearly indicate what you are looking for.  Lastly, your seq in the comments is different from the one in the question, thereby not to be used within strsplit. Only use seq that was matched. not a new one